# Get inode for lookup in /proc/net/udp

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I am trying to programmatically track the amount of data in my receive buffer. I am receiving UDP data. After doing some research it seems that the only way to do this in Linux is to look at /proc/net/udp. This seems like a good solution until I realized that two applications could be listening to the same multicast group and I need to tell them apart. It seems that I am supposed to do this by determining what my inode is.

I spend some time looking into this and there are suggestions that sockfd_lookup or sock_from_file is the way to go but on my CentOS Linux machine, these functions do not seem to be available.

Can someone please help me to figure out which line in /proc/net/udp belongs to my application?

I started using the ioctl (handle, FIONREAD, &bytesInBuffer) call only to discover that in Linux this only returns the size of the first datagram packet in the buffer.

Google seems to suggest that the sockfd_lookup call can be used to get the inode but a grep in my /usr/local/include/ does not return these functions.

My linux/net.h seems pretty bare-bone compared to some I can find on google which includes structs like "socket" which has the sock member which I believe has the inode information. My linux/net.h on CentOs only is 58 lines long and has only a few #defines and an enum.

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem to be related to inodes, which makes the title kind of misleading.

Comment: My understanding is that I need to get the inod that belongs to my socket handle in order to lookup the correct line in the inode column in /proc/net/udp. My question is about how in C++ on Linux to get this inode with a side question of whether I am approaching the problem correctly by thinking that getting the inode is the right way to go here.

Comment: to help with "whether I am approaching the problem correctly", why do you want this info?  I'm struggling to think of why an application would need to know this about itself, maybe for benchmarking or maybe for monitoring utilisation?

Answer (score 1):

after a bit of fiddling I noticed that `readlink("/proc/self/fd/$fd")` (under Linux 5.3) gives me something like:

> `socket:[3753088]`

back.  I can parse this and use the resulting digits to look up the relevant line in `/proc/net/udp`:

> ```
>   sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops             
>  2867: 00000000:0BB8 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 3753088 2 000000003ae8e911 0
> ```

that said, I don't understand why you'd want to do this, but never mind! 
 I'm also not sure why you don't just look up by sock&peer name, which might be easier